# Whitelist callback plugin in AWX (Ansible tower)

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I am working on callback plugin https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html
and found I can control to whitelist a specific callback plugin like this way in a playbook run.

```
ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_WHITELIST=notify_me ansible-playbook node-build.yml
```

I am looking for anyone who has done or an idea to do so with AWX (Ansible Tower).

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I confirmed it's not possible to directly do an override via ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_WHITELIST due to how AWX needs to run its own callback.